# Bash script find pattern and replace by filename

Tags: bash, shell, sed, xargs

I'm trying to find all files of a specific folder and which contains text "TO_BE_REPLACED" and I would like to replace this string by the filename without the characters Impl.
I mean, having a file called MyServiceImpl with text "TO_BE_REPLACED" I would like to replace it with the text "MyService".
How I can achieve that? I tried this way without results:

```
find src/main/java/com/shn/*/server/service/impl/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i "" "s/TO_BE_REPLACED/<filename>/g"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
while read -r filename
do
  sed -i "s/TO_BE_REPLACED/MyService/g" $filename
done < <(find "src/main/java/com/shn/*/server/service/impl/" -type f)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU Parallel >= 20140822:

```
find . -type f | parallel -q sed -i "" -e 's/TO_BE_REPLACED/{=s:.*/::;s/Impl$//=}/g' {}
```

The trick here is to use a perl expression to go from `.../MyServiceImpl` to `MyService` and use that in `sed`.